# Mysql error #1064 when renaming columns

Tags: mysql

I am gettting a mysql error when trying to change the column names on these tables:

```
alter field_data_commerce_customer_address CHANGE field_mcaf_middle_name commerce_customer_address_middle_name varchar (255);
alter field_revision_commerce_customer_address CHANGE field_mcaf_middle_name commerce_customer_address_middle_name varchar (255);
```

This is my error

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'field_data_commerce_customer_address CHANGE field_mcaf_middle_name commerce_cust' at line 1
```

I checked the table and column names and they are correct. What am I missing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You missed 'TABLE' word:

```
alter TABLE field_data_commerce_customer_address CHANGE field_mcaf_middle_name commerce_customer_address_middle_name varchar (255);
alter TABLE field_revision_commerce_customer_address CHANGE field_mcaf_middle_name commerce_customer_address_middle_name varchar (255);
```